# Setting size of sIFR text

Tags: css, sifr, font-size

I'm trying to style a couple of instances of sIFR text in a site I'm working on, and I don't quite understand the technique recommended in [the styling documentation](http://wiki.novemberborn.net/sifr3/Styling).

It says that: "When specified for the .sIFR-root class and given a px unit, this determines the actual font size sIFR uses to render the Flash movie", but then warns you off of doing this as it will make the text unscalable.

It then says that "When specified for other selectors, use the % unit to make the font size relative to the main font size," but I don't know what "other selectors" they're referring to there. It says that styling must be specified in the sifr-config.js file, but the only place in that file I can see where you can enter your own CSS is the .sIFR-root class. Here's the code that calls each instance of sIFR:

```
sIFR.replace(inkburrow, {
```

selector: '#sidebar h3',
  css: '.sIFR-root { background-color: #F7F8F2; color: #222222; font-size: 24px; }'
});

(in this instance, the specific font, colours, etc. are those I'm using). So I'm not sure where other than in the .sIFR-root class they want you to put a relative font-size. Putting any unit other than pixels in the .sIFR-root class doesn't work - I tried it. And giving any kind of font styling to the selector being replaced (in this case #sidebar h3) in the site's regular style sheet has no effect - tried that too.

As you can see, currently I'm doing it the way they warned against: setting a px size in .sIFR-root. But I'd rather be able to use a relative size if possible - I just can't figure out where I'm supposed to put it!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have font-size: 100%; in your body { } style in the main style sheet.

Assume that most browsers will have a default font size of 16px. So if you want your font to be 24px, set the .sIFR-root CSS to say font-size: 150%; and it will resize all of your sIFR text to 24px with relative size.

If it still doesn't work, take a look at it using the Firebug add-on in Firefox, and see why that style is being overridden by another style somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't specify any font size in the `sIFR.replace()`, sIFR will use the font size from the document.

The percentages are useful if you want to mix different font sizes within a sIFR Flash movie without specifying the main font size in pixels.